# Pathfinding javascript algorithm not working as it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, algorithm, path-finding

I'm writing pathfinding algorithm, however I'm stuck on one thing. Algorithm gets starting cell and adds it to queue, flags it as visited and prints number in cell on screen (number shows distance of current cell from starting cells). Then for first element of queue it checks its neighbours. If neighbour is not wall or hasn't been visited yet, he is added to queue. Then first element is removed from queue and whole function is repeated until length of queue equals to 0.

I can't get one thing working, when filling queue with cells and giving cells their distance number, result should be like this:

```
S12
1#2
22E
```

where # is a wall, S is starting point, and E is goal point. However when algorithm is run, it produces following result:

```
S12
2#3
33E
```

It seems that some cells have their distance number increased more than once, which shouldn't happen. In code I've added additional boolean flag whether cell distance number already has been incremented or not and additional condition which increases distance number only when it hasn't been increased so far. Help with pointing out where I made mistake will be greatly appreciated. Pathfinding function:

```
function findPath(startCell, goalCell) {
  var queue = [];

  queue.push({
    cell: startCell,
    hasBeenIncremented: true,
    hasBeenSearched: false,
    searchDistance: undefined
  });
  queue[0].searchDistance = 0;

  fillPath();

  function fillPath() {
    queue[0].cell.hasBeenSearched = true;
    pointColor(queue[0].cell.x, queue[0].cell.y, 'darkred');
    setInnerHTML(queue[0].cell.x, queue[0].cell.y, queue[0].searchDistance);

    for (var i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
      if (queue[0].cell.x + i < 0 || queue[0].cell.x + i > boardHeight - 1) {
        continue;
      }
      for (var j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        if (queue[0].cell.y + j < 0 || queue[0].cell.y + j > boardWidth - 1) {
          continue;
        }
        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
          continue;
        }
        if (getCell(queue[0].cell.x + i, queue[0].cell.y + j).hasWall == true || getCell(queue[0].cell.x + i, queue[0].cell.y + j).hasBeenSearched == true) {
          continue;
        }
        if (queue[0].cell.x == goalCell.x && queue[0].cell.y == goalCell.y) {
          pointColor(goalCell.x, goalCell.y, 'darkred');
          setInnerHTML(goalCell.x, goalCell.y, '*');
          return 'path completed';
        }

        queue.push({
          cell: getCell(queue[0].cell.x + i, queue[0].cell.y + j),
          hasBeenSearched: false,
          searchDistance: undefined,
          hasBeenIncremented: false
        });
        if(queue[queue.length - 1].hasBeenIncremented != true) {
          queue[queue.length - 1].searchDistance = queue[0].searchDistance + 1;
          queue[queue.length - 1].hasBeenIncremented = true;
        }

      }
    }
    queue.shift();
    if (queue.length > 0) {
      setTimeout(fillPath, 1000);
    }
  }

}
```

JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/s8texvxa/2/ (this is not a complete algorithm - only first part of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform a check before queueing, but it may be in the queue via some other path but not yet checked, so it is still seen as unvisited.

Note that  if a cell can be reach via multiple paths, you must make sure you use the shortest distance.

Looks like you are using a breadth-first algorithm so it should be sufficient to mark a cell as visited when queueing it so it won't get added again.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I fully understand - cell that already have distance can not be added to queue again, because they have "haveBeenSearched" flag set to true, and they are ommited in 'for' loop in fragment `if (getCell(queue[0].cell.x + i, queue[0].cell.y + j).hasWall == true || getCell(queue[0].cell.x + i, queue[0].cell.y + j).hasBeenSearched == true) {
          continue;
        }`

Comment: You perform a check before queueing, but it may be in the queue via some other path but not yet checked, so it is still seen as unvisited. Note that if a cell can be reach via multiple paths, you must make sure you use the shortest distance.

Comment: Looks like you are using a breadth-first algorithm so it may be sufficient to mark a cell as visited when queueing it.

Comment: Right, that was the issue! Some cells were added to queue more than once. Could you please edit your answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Modified my answer.